# Explicit solutions of C(n,2)=x^2 ?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

"On a Diophantine Equation" paper of Erdös, at some point it is said that it is well known that $C(n,2)=x^2$ has infinitely many integer solutions. I am just wondering the formula generating all possible $n \geq 2$,because I wonder whether they all come by integer solutions of $2x^2-y^2=\pm 1$ Pell's equation generated by fundamental unit, or is it possible to have different $n$'s that do not come from the solutions of the pell's equation.

For example $C(2,2)=1$ a square, $C(9,2)=36$ a square too, so the first two $n$'s are 2,9.

One can also see from the solutions of $2x^2-y^2=\pm 1$ pell's equation, by take $x=1, y=0$ 
for $n=2=2*1$ and take $x=2, y=3$ for $n=9=3^2$.

Comment: What is $C(n, 2)?$

Comment: I would guess it is $\dbinom{n}{2}$...

Comment: $n$ and $n-1$ are relatively prime. Voting to close.

Comment: @fedja, what is the relevance of $n$ and $n-1$ being relatively prime?  The equation $C(n,2)=x^2$ rewrites to $(2n-1)^2 - 8x^2 = 1$, so all solutions come from solutions to Pell's equation.

Comment: @Barry seems to have answered the question, so it is safe to close now.

Comment: I view it as $n(n-1)=2x^2$, so $n=y^2$ and $n-1=2z^2$ or vice versa, both options resulting in Pell's equations mentioned in the original post. Anyway, no matter how you think of it, it is pretty obvious. Hence the closing vote.

Comment: Barry answered a question (solutions come from a Pell equation), but not the question (do all solutions come from the particular, different, Pell equations). I don't follow the OP's last paragraph, the connection between x,y,n, that is implied is what? 

Comment: Kevin, have you read what I wrote in response to Barry?

Comment: @fedja: no, I hadn't read it. Our comments crossed in the ether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach to the problem, at least for non-number theorists, is to ask Mathematica:

> Select[Range[10000], IntegerQ[Sqrt[Binomial[#, 2]]] &]

and you find that the first examples are

> {1, 2, 9, 50, 289, 1682, 9801}

Then go to the OEIS (https://oeis.org/) and input that. You find that this is sequence A055997 (https://oeis.org/A055997), and the OEIS response is together with generating functions, recurrence relations, citations, and more.

One of those references is to an article titled "Discovering the Square-Triangular Numbers", which seems a promising title. The citation is to the Fibonacci Quarterly, and a little googling finds that their old issues are online (http://www.fq.math.ca/list-of-issues.html), and this particular article (by Phil Lafer) is, too (http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/9-1/lafer.pdf).

The article reads nicely (thank you Phil Lafer), and the Pell equation $2x^2-y^2=1$ does indeed make a fundamental appearance.

Comment: Kevin i am sorry of being too late not saying thank you by the time you spent your time for this not so loved question.